# Flex application packaged in AIR doesn't show it's window

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have a Flex application that builds and runs from Eclipse without any problems. I've created an Ant build based on the sample provided by Adobe and builds the application and packages it up into an AIR application. No errors occur during the build process and an AIR file is created.

The problem is that when I install the AIR application and run it, there is no UI at all. The process is running because I can see it in Task Manager but I can't see the app window. I've commented out all of my initial code so just the first window should appear but still nothing.

Is there anything that I might have missed in the build to cause this problem?

Thanks in advance

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the problem. Turns out I was missing the following parameter in the Ant build script:

```
<arg value="-include-libraries=${libs}"/>
```